# render a individual field in a form-inline using 'as_crispy_field'

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-filters

I need to render individual fields from my `Form` so I use the filter `|as_crispy_field` from `crispy-forms` and use bootstrap 3 for the style but I need to do it in a `form-inline` like the first example here [bootstrap example page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) so I tried to do it like this:

```
template.html

<form class="form-inline">{% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.name|as_crispy_field }}
</form>
```

But the label shows above the TextInput field and not in-line as I need. **How can I do this using |as_crispy_field?**

**EDIT:** Here is the HTML after the render with crispy

```
<form class="form-inline"><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='****...' />
    <div id="div_id_name" class="form-group">
            <label for="id_name" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Name<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
            </label>
                <div class="controls ">
                    <input class="form-control textinput textInput form-control" id="id_name" maxlength="100" name="name" type="text" />
                </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is your viewport "at least 768px wide"? If so, please post the crispy rendered HTML.

Comment: yes it is, already post the rendered HTML

Answer (score 0):

The one you linked to, with the labels on the left of the fields, is called "form-horizontal" in Crispy. It is [explained here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#bootstrap3-horizontal-forms). You need to set these `helper` properties

```
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

Actual inline forms, with the label displayed inside the fields are right below on the same page. You only need to set two helper properties

```
helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
```

That should do it, if I understood your question correctly.